# Add empty document to collection

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add a new document and collection to my database. I know I can just add a document and if the collection where it is supposed to be will be added if doe not exist. 
My question is: how can I add an empty document to a new collection in my database?

I have tried this code, from the android developers site:

```
ApiFuture<WriteResult> future = db.collection("cities").document("LA");
// ...
// future.get() blocks on response
System.out.println("Update time : " + future.get().getUpdateTime());
```

But it gives me error in the ApiFuture part that I can't resolve.
So I tried this:

```
db.collection(mail).document("tarefa");
```

(mail is a string)
But it does not work.
Does anyone know what I should do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `db.collection("cities").document("LA")` only creates a reference to a document. It doesn't write any data yet.

This is probably the shortest way to write an empty document:

```
db.collection("cities").document("LA").set(new HashMap<String, Object>())
```

If that doesn't work, an `update` should definitely work:

```
db.collection("cities").document("BJ")
    .set(new HashMap<String, Object>(), SetOptions.merge());
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @FranfvanPuffelen. I actually had to merge the two options you gave me. The first one had an error (apparently I can't assign a document a null value), but when I did the second one it just did not work. So I used the first one, but with a new HashMap. As you can see in my answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good to hear. I updated the first snippet in my answer. I'm not sure why the second wouldn't work though. :-/

Answer (score 2):

So I adapted the answer from Frank van Puffelen and it solved my problem. Here is how I did it:

```
db.collection(mail).document("tarefa").set(new HashMap<String, Object>());
```